# What happened to the Boar Brothers?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

At the end of The Incredible Hulk #3, the Boar Brothers are in rough shape.  They're laying on two small outcroppings in a sea of liquid hot magma, and both appear very injured (one makes comments about being blind and has either orange Hulk goop or magma pouring out of his eye sockets and both make comments about not being able to hear).

The Hulk (original flavor) did give them a pretty intense beating before smashing a big hole far beneath the surface of the Earth, which they then fell down before ending up on their tiny magma islands.  They both look fairly uninjured before the fall.

How did the  Boar Brothers get injured so badly, and is it orange Hulk blood or magma covering both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just implied that the beating + the fall left them in this state.  It's kinda grim, but I took this to mean they're basically dead.